# How to get primary category name in Wordpress new version

Tags: categories

There is a new feature in wordpress introducing primary category.
When you select a category, primary category can be specified.

My question is how can I get that primary category name using Wordpress Core functions?

if there is no function, can you help me to get the first child of main category?

for example:
- main category
-- child cat 1
-- child cat 2
-- child cat 3

I need to get -- child cat 1.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Primary category ? Can you please help ME to find a article and this new concept primary category ?

Comment: Install the latest version of wordpress then add new post select multiple categories one of the categories can be selected as primary category

Comment: Or maybe I am mistaking and a plugin giving me this options?!

Comment: I don't see this. Are you taking about this https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-3-1/ ?

Comment: @MMTdesigner It's Yoast SEO that is providing the 'primary category' feature. They are using it for breadcrumb. It's not from WordPress core. :)

Comment: could you answer the second question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that this question is getting a lot of attentions since the past year, I thought to answer this question in the right way.

There is not primary category in wordpress if you have installed **Yoast SEO** plugin then a new feature will be appear on **Single Posts** category selection in admin area in order to choose primary category .

To get that primary category you can use the following function I came up with:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_primary_taxonomy_id' ) ) {
function get_primary_taxonomy_id( $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
    $prm_term = '';
    if (class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {
        $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( $taxonomy, $post_id );
        $prm_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
    }
    if ( !is_object($wpseo_primary_term) && empty( $prm_term ) ) {
        $term = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
        if (isset( $term ) && !empty( $term ) ) {
            return wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy )[0]->term_id;
        }
        return '';

    }
    return $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
}
}
```

First it will check to see if Yoast SEO is being installed and activated then it  will try to get primary category. if Yost  is not installed then it will get all of the categories and returns the first one.

Notice how this function also works for custom post types with custom taxonomies.

At the end this function returns the category (term) ID if you want to get the category (term) object you can use `get_term($ID, $taxonomy)` and pass in the ID.

New Edit:

If you are using Rank Math and you want to get primary taxonomy set using this plugin then the following piece of code might help:

```
   if (class_exists('RankMath')) {
        $primary_tax = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rank_math_primary_category', true );
        if (!empty($primary_tax)) {
            return get_term( $primary_tax, $taxonomy );
        }
    }
```

I suggest to add this after Yoast `if` statement.

Answer (score 6):

I have editted the [MMT Designer function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/304061/138418). This works better for me:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_primary_taxonomy_id' ) ) {
    function get_primary_taxonomy_id( $post_id, $taxonomy ) {
        $prm_term = '';
        if (class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {
            $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( $taxonomy, $post_id );
            $prm_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
        }
        if ( !is_object($wpseo_primary_term) || empty( $prm_term ) ) {
            $term = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
            if (isset( $term ) && !empty( $term ) ) {
                return $term[0]->term_id;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
        return $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question: [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) allows you to pass a whole bunch of arguments, one of which happens to be child categories.

First get the parent category. I've used `get_category_by_slug` here, but you could use any other way to get it, for instance Yoasts function to retrieve the primary category.

```
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'category-name' );
```

Then get all child categories:

```
$args = array(
'type'                     => 'post',
'child_of'                 => $category->term_id,
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC', // or any order you like
'hide_empty'               => FALSE,
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
); 
$child_categories = get_categories($args );
```

Finally select the first element if there is any:

```
if !empty($child_categories) $first_child = $child_categories[0];
```

Comment: Tanks this is nice way to do it, I have found other ways but I guess your way is more efficient thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

this is not for wordpress but for seo plugin, you could use following function

```
function get_post_primary_category($post_id, $term='category', 
   $return_all_categories=false){
   $return = array();

if (class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')){
    // Show Primary category by Yoast if it is enabled & set
    $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( $term, $post_id );
    $primary_term = get_term($wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term());

    if (!is_wp_error($primary_term)){
        $return['primary_category'] = $primary_term;
    }
}

if (empty($return['primary_category']) || $return_all_categories){
    $categories_list = get_the_terms($post_id, $term);

    if (empty($return['primary_category']) && !empty($categories_list)){
        $return['primary_category'] = $categories_list[0];  //get the first 

    }
    if ($return_all_categories){
        $return['all_categories'] = array();

        if (!empty($categories_list)){
            foreach($categories_list as &$category){
                $return['all_categories'][] = $category->term_id;
            }
        }
    }
}

return $return;
}
```

this function is written by [lab21.gr](https://www.lab21.gr/blog/wordpress-get-primary-category-post)

Answer (score 2):

A native Wordpress solution to return the current parent category.

```
function primary_categories($arr_excluded_cats) {

if($arr_excluded_cats == null) {
    $arr_excluded_cats = array();
}

$post_cats = get_the_category();

$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 0
);

    $primary_categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($primary_categories as $primary_category) {

        foreach ($post_cats as $post_cat) {
            if(($primary_category->slug == $post_cat->slug) && (!in_array($primary_category->slug, $arr_excluded_cats))) {
                return $primary_category->slug;
            }
        }
    }
}

//if you have more than two parent categories associated with the post, you can delete the ones you don't want here
$dont_return_these = array(
        'receitas','enciclopedico'
    );

//use the function like this:
echo primary_categories($dont_return_these);
```

Comments:

- if you only have one parent category by post, pass null instead of array
- if you want another output instead of slug change this to return $primary_category-> slug;

Answer (score 1):

I've just refactored [Eqhes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/138418/eqhes) answer. A little cleaner code :)

```
if (!function_exists('get_primary_taxonomy_id')) {
    function get_primary_taxonomy_id($post_id, $taxonomy) {
        $prm_term = '';
        $wpseo_primary_term = '';

        if (class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {
            $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term($taxonomy, $post_id);
            $prm_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
        }

        if (is_object($wpseo_primary_term) && !empty($prm_term)) {
            return $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
        }

        $term = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);

        if (isset($term) && !empty($term)) {
            return $term[0]->term_id;
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use sCategory Permalink plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/scategory-permalink/

```
$category_primary_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_category_permalink', true);
if (!empty($category_primary_id)) {
    $category = get_category($category_primary_id);
    var_dump($category->name);
}
```

Comment: What is `_category_permalink` ? I'm not familiar with that metakey. Where do I put this code? Could you [edit your answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/262015/edit) using the [edit link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/262015/edit) above and add in some detail to your answer, please?

Comment: > _What_ _is_ _category_permalink_ _?_
Each primary category for post saved as _category_permalink

Comment: > _I'm_ _not_ _familiar_ _with_ _that_ _metakey._
Use SQL query for find all metakeys for post:
`SELECT * FROM postmeta WHERE post_id = ID`

Comment: > _Where_ _do_ _I_ _put_ _this_ _code?_
For example, you can insert this code to 
wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/single.php
or some different PHP file, where you show **Primary** category name for post